# Beamer Block gaussian blurred?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Currently, I have my beamer theme so that block environments are transparent. Would it be possible to have them gaussian blurred (blurring obviously the background to create an annoying Windows 7 effect) as well? I think people have found ways to make tikz do this, but what about as a default thing (for every block environment)?

Currently I have this effect:
[image: beamer block environment]

Why I would want to gauss blur? So I can have more annoying backgrounds in my slides, the blur would make the text in the alert environment readable in a lot of circumstances

- See as example how the terminal is blurred. It's transparent but one can still read the text no matter what is going on with the desktop

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a very, let's say "adventurous" idea. Your better chance to improve readability is to only make the background semi-transparent instead of also applying this to your font.

Comment: E.g. simply using some settings like https://i.stack.imgur.com/akq99.png would already improve readability a lot

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that is the idea..

Comment: that is not what i want to do. i specifically want to blur. why you misinterpret what i want to do as the main goal is beyond me. Just because you don't know how to achieve that. So why say anything? And instead you choose to focus on some subgoal I had.

Comment: Good luck with the blur!

Comment: i already found a way to do that, albeit with imagemagic. i was just looking for a more direct route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure latex approach:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{jwst}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\def\myblur{4}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{blur}[1][]{%
  #1,
  enhanced,
  remember,
  frame hidden,
  interior hidden,
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  coltitle=black,
  underlay={
    \begin{tcbclipframe}
      \begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt]
        \fill[white] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \foreach \x in {-10,-7.5,...,10}{
        \foreach \y in {-10,-7.5,...,10}{
          \node[opacity=0.01] at ([yshift=\y,xshift=\x]current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{jwst}};
        }}
      \end{scope}
    \end{tcbclipframe}
   }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{blur}[
    title={My title},
  ]
  some test
  \end{blur}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

(example image taken from https://webbtelescope.org/contents/news-releases/2022/news-2022-031)

If you already have a blurred version of the background:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{jwst}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\def\myblur{4}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{blur}[1][]{%
  #1,
  enhanced,
  remember,
  frame hidden,
  interior hidden,
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  coltitle=black,
  underlay={
    \begin{tcbclipframe}
      \begin{scope}[inner sep=0pt,remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[white] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \node[opacity=0.9] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{blured}};
      \end{scope}
    \end{tcbclipframe}
   }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{blur}[
    title={My title},
  ]
  some test
  \end{blur}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution, but can it be invoked automatically with beamer's \begin{block}\end{block}? I use org mode which has a short-hand invocation of block environment, which preserves eg multiple columns. And more importantly, it preserves the itemize environment (you can see me use bullet blocks in my picture's example). So that is convenient as a no brain way to make slides

Comment: @georg You can redefine the block `\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{\begin{blur}[title={\insertblocktitle}]}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{\end{blur}}`

Comment: thank you. i noticed your answers before and i think you do the highest level's work

Comment: is there a way to eliminate the white border coming through at the edges? It looks aliased or rough

Comment: That's probably a viewer issue.